# C#: How to parse a user query

Tags: c#, parsing, search

How to parse such a query to sql?.. or
Do you know any open source parsers which can parse it:

```
(((adsfa ≤ "value") AND (adsfa > "value")) OR (adsfa = "value")) 
AND (adsfa ≤ "value") OR ((adsfa ≤ "value") AND (adsfa ≤ "value")) 
AND (adsfa ≤ "value")
```

I've tried to build my own algorithm with `string.Split(stringSeparators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`
algorithm is getting more and more complicated but i'm finding more combinations that it can't parse.

---

- adsfa is column name
- ≤ is operator
- "value" is value

UPDATED: **Thank you all, may be I'll use one of the parsers in the next version.**

Comment: To the close-voters: What's not understandable here? O_o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I developed something like this myself using the [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) library. It's still in alpha, but has been stable for me so far. Note though that I used it to parse expressions that were written by other programmers, not user input.

Here's another idea - if you trust the source of the query, and just need to convert it to proper SQL, maybe a few simple `string.Replace()` would be enough? It's practically SQL already, just the operators are weird characters.

Comment: At the end of the day, i see that this pseudo code looks like SQL. May be you are right - the simplest way is just to string.Replace()

Answer (score 1):

If those are the only expressions you need to parse you can probably write the parser by hand in C#. For the brackets you need to recurse, because you don't know how deep they can be nested. Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/TinyLisp.aspx) I wrote a while back, you can probably rewrite it to fit your needs.

When things get more complicated writing a parser by hand becomes hard, then you probably be better of using a toolkit. My weapon of choice these days in [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/), although it's in F# not C#. That is very very powerful and flexible.

Else I've had good experience with [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Maybe you don't need to have a full parsers etc. Tell us what you want to do exactly, why do you want to read these expressions? Maybe there's another way.

GJ

Answer (score 0):

This looks like real trouble.
Normally I would do something like this with a parser-generator/combinator-library like FParsec in F#. But I don't think there is anything like this for C# (Luke Hoben did something similar [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/08/19/monadic-parser-combinators-using-c-3-0.aspx))

Can you switch to F# for this part of your project?